The equivalent of a paraprosdokian at the beginning of sentence?
What is a literary technique that is like paraprosdokian but used at the beginning of the sentence for a similar effect?
I'd love to know what the term for this is, and there are certainly styles of writing where a surprising statement is made at the beginning of a sentence, and as you get to the end you realize that it might mean something a little bit different than what you thought previously.
I think this is very typical of the short opening statement in a novel, which takes on a slightly deeper meaning once you get to the end of the book. But I am trying to think of something recent that I have come across condensed into a sentence.
As an example, if a paraprosdokian is something like:

Hospitality is making your guests feel like they’re at home even if you wish they were.

Then the opposite to that might be something like:

Don't insist on making the guests feel like they're at home if you are not prepared to make them wash the dishes.

I didn't expect this question to cause so much controversy, and I am happy for it to be closed, but I thought I would offer my thoughts on something interesting I found with the second example.
Maybe it is not the exact opposite of paraprosdokian, but it is still kind of interesting. When you read the first part of the sentence it in my example, it seems strange, and when you read the second part it makes more sense. When you read the whole sentence together again, it means something different. I felt like my example kind of satisfies this. The first part of the sentence by itself sounds contrary to what you would say to your guests. The second part makes more sense because to feel like you're at home is to do the things that you would do at home. Finally, when you read the whole sentence again, it points to the fact that we don't really mean what we say in the first part of the sentence.

How can this be at the beginning? The whole point of a paraprosdokian is that it defies expectations set at the beginning.

I'm struggling to see how a sentence can exist other than where the incongruity only becomes apparent when both 'halves' of the sentence etc have been read. Certainly, a sentence/discourse may start with a jolting first statement; this is called a startle set (occasionally). But the whole point of a paraprosdokian is a sudden incongruous change in direction. The second statement is as necessary as the first, and neither could stand on its own as a startling contrast. //  ishtar gives an example of bathos, rhetorical use/abuse of anticlimax.

@Mitch How is this not a paraprosdokian? And even if one is looking merely for a startling first statement etc followed by a second statement in some way contrastive, 'Don't insist on making the guests feel like they're at home' hardly qualifies.

@EdwinAshworth I don't know. Maybe that's the start of your answer?

@Mitch I close-voted for the reason given above.

@EdwinAshworth thanks for the edits.

Most sentences convey information along the way. When it contradicts the initial expectation that is just better information rather than the same old same old.
"I'm confused!", she ejaculated.

Are you perhaps asking a slightly different question than the title implies? From the title, it sounds like you simply want a word for a reverse-order paraprosdokian, but this would also yield a paraprosdokian because in both cases the expectation initially established would be overturned. But perhaps you want a word specifically for sentences which initially seem surprising or absurd, but after being read to their conclusion turn out to yield a more quotidian result?

@gaufridus at this point I would be happy with anything to be honest :p

I believe the term paraprosdokian could be expanded to include a surprising or unexpected beginning. Per Wikipedia:  "Paraprosdokian" comes from the Greek "παρά", meaning "against", and "προσδοκία", meaning "expectation".

Wikipedia describes paradokian as follows:

A paraprosdokian (/pærəprɒsˈdoʊkiən/) is a figure of speech in which the latter part of a sentence, phrase, or larger discourse is surprising or unexpected in a way that causes the reader or listener to reframe or reinterpret the first part. It is frequently used for humorous or dramatic effect, sometimes producing an anticlimax.

The term refers to the incongruity, not to its parts individually. So asking for a related word for the beginning rather than the end is somewhat like asking for a word that means marriage, but which applies to the wife rather than the husband. Or alternatively, it is like asking for a term for swap where the items are returned to their original places. The terms would still be marriage and swap because these terms deal with the whole, not the parts.
One could construct terms with ‘opposite’ prefixes, such as prodokian or antidokian, but they would likely have completely different senses from paradokian. If we draw their meanings from the Greek roots, the former might be ‘prior understanding’ and the latter ‘replaced understanding’.
If you don’t mind casting your net wider, anacolouthon, although referencing more jarring incongruities, has the ana- prefix to (arguably) explicitly reference the earlier item in the rhetoric.
